# Spring Security 3.2: @Secured annotations not taken into account

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to secure my RESTful API using Spring 3.2.4 and Spring Security 3.2 using the @Secured annotations. I have the following setup:

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:spring/*.xml
        /WEB-INF/classes/security/security-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Servlet configuration -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/servlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.rest.controller" />
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

security-context.xml

```
<beans:bean id="merchantUserDetailsService" class="com.mycompany.rest.security.CustomUserDetailsService" /> 

<http auto-config="false" create-session="never">
    <http-basic />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

I am programmatically assigning custom roles (ROLE_GROUP, ROLE_DIVISION, ROLE_READ, ROLE_WRITE) in the customUserDetailsService to the user and this works fine.

One of my controllers:

```
@Secured("ROLE_DIVISION")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<List<CustomerResource>> getCustomer() throws ResourceDoestNotExistException {
    List<Customer> providers = // retrieve providers from DAO
    List<CustomerResource> resources = customerResourceAssembler.toResources(customers);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(resources, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Now to my problem, the @Secured annotations are being ignored. I want to use the @Secured annotation to avoid having to define multiple 's in the  configuration. Spring Security works fine when I add at least one , but how can avoid defining them and instead rely on the @Secured annotations?

I can now access the method above with an user with the role "ROLE_GROUP".

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have everything right except that you've enabled the wrong type of annotations. If you check the documentation for [`global-method-security`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-global-method-security) you'll see there's a separate attribute called `secured-annotations` which enables `@Secured`.

Comment: Sorry, that was me copy pasting the wrong snippet of code (was trying something). I updated the original post.

Comment: It shouldn't affect the method interception either way. If it's being applied you should get an exception. If you are sure the method is actually being called,check it is actually being proxied (add a breakpoint and look at the the stack, or add a Thread.dumpStack() call).

Comment: The method is called and proxied by Spring Security as well. Can't get my head around why this is not working correctly. Next thing to try is to create a new simple project to try it out.